# Importing RecordType as test data with Test.loadData()

Tags: unit-test, record-type

I am trying to import some test data before tests with a csv file and the Test.load() method.
I am not being able to figure out how to declare the load method for the RecordTypes I have in a file.
Here is what I have:

```
static testMethod void init() {
    List<sObject> recordTypes = Test.loadData(?????, 'esb_record_type_test_data');
    List<sObject> accounts = Test.loadData(Account.sObjectType, 'esb_account_test_data');
    List<sObject> contacts = Test.loadData(Contact.sObjectType, 'esb_contact_test_data');
    List<sObject> customers = Test.loadData(Customer__c.sObjectType, 'esb_customer_test_data');
}
```

What should I declare in?

Comment: you do not need to load record types. They are available during apex testing. Using fake record types during test would not be a good practice as it would potentially alter the outcome to be different than in actual production day to day use with the real recordtpyes

Comment: Eric is correct. There should, however, be a `RecordType.sObjectType` that you can pass in.

Comment: I've opened idea to allow use of a RecordType DeveloperName in place of the RecordTypeId https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PTveQAG

Answer (score 7):

1. Record types are not separate object. Adding extra column in your CSV file with RecordTypeID should work. So while inserting from Test.Load(), record will be created based on record types.
2. Alternately if there is change in recordtypeid use below syntax to get RecordtypeId and logic.

Example code:

```
Id RecordTypeIdValue = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Development').getRecordTypeId();

for(Account accountrecord : accounts) {
    accountrecord.Recordtypeid=RecordTypeIdValue;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: So what you're saying is to load the records through the test.loaddata and then set the record type after? What record type do they have when they are loaded? I assume the default record type for the user running the test.

Comment: The issue with putting the recordrypeid in the static resource is that it changes between environments. It is possible, you just need to have instance specific static resources to load your data. I would prefer to have one resource, load them, query the recordtypeid and then set it in the test. That way your test methods and resources are the same for every environment.