# Can Person Account records be loaded from a Static Resource as test data without a RecordTypeID column?

Tags: apex, unit-test, static-resources

### Question

In an org with Person Accounts enabled, it possible to use `Test.loadData()` to load test Account records from a .csv file as Person Accounts (not as Business Accounts), but without hardcoding their RecordTypeIds in the CSV?

---

**EDIT**: So far, I've experimented with a few solutions, to no avail.

### Attempt 1: Loading the Account records from a CSV with only the following three columns: `Id, FirstName, LastName`

When I did this, I was unable to replicate the behavior detailed in [Inserting person accounts in test mode](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121270/inserting-person-accounts-in-test-mode/193944#193944) in which Salesforce automatically knows what type of Account to create based on what fields are populated. Upon calling `Test.loadData()`, I received an error stating that the required field `Name` was missing, which I believe corresponds to Business Accounts.

When I added the fourth column, Name, to the existing csv as an experiment, calling `Test.loadData()` successfully inserted the Account records, but as expected, they were Business Accounts, and the FirstName and LastName fields on the inserted Accounts were null.

### Attempt 2: Loading the Account records from a csv with no RecordTypeIds, then later dynamically assigning RecordTypeIds through Apex.

In addition to the Account CSV (with four columns, including Name, since I can't get around the Name required field error), I loaded Contacts from a CSV with columns: `Id, AccountId, FirstName, LastName`, such that each Contact only looked up to one Account, and no Contact looked up to the same Account.

In a test setup method, after loading the Accounts and Contacts from their respective Static Resource CSVs, I queried for one Person Account Record Type. Then, I iterated through the list of loaded Accounts, and assigned the Id of the queried Record Type to each Account's RecordTypeId. I assigned no other values to any other field on any other object.

Then, I called a DML update on the list of Account records. That is when I receive the error: `Cannot specify any additional fields when marrying or separating a Person-Account: []`

### Attempt 3: Adding the IsPersonAccount column to the CSV, with values `true`.

The loaded records had IsPersonAccount set to `true`, but they were created with a RecordTypeId corresponding to Business Accounts.

Comment: Could you load the Account records from the static resource without specifying the RecordTypeId and then dynamically assign the correct ID afterwards in Apex? This was suggested in [Importing RecordType as test data with Test.loadData()](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/65153/102)

Comment: Another interesting suggestion in [Inserting person accounts in test mode](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/193944/102). As long as the user has access to the Person Account record type then setting the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields should imply a Person Account and assign the correct record type.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, @DanielBallinger! Since posting the question, I've tried both: (1) loading the Account records from the CSV without specifying the RecordTypeId and dynamically assigning the ID to each record in Apex, and (2) loading the Account records from the CSV with FirstName and LastName columns; both to no success.

(Unsure if it has something to do with config settings in the environment I'm working with, but I will update my question with the solutions I tried and the error messages I received.)

Comment: OK. I wasn't certain about those approaches (hence the comments).  Please do update the question with the error messages when you tried those approaches. It might help someone else identify a solution or at least rule them out as ways to load Person Accounts.

Comment: If you can't find a way to make this work... perhaps you could prepare some Person Accounts as JSON instead. Then you can query its body, deserialize and insert in just a few lines

Comment: @CharlesT
Posting JSON in test class just increases its size and taht leads to long compilation times. There is also limit of characters you can have in a APEX class.

Comment: I'm not saying to put it in the compiled code. I'm saying put the JSON in a Static Resource. Query the Static Resource's body in the test class and deserialize.

Comment: For Attempt 2 and the message `Cannot specify any additional fields when marrying or separating a Person-Account`. Try having *only* the RecordTypeID and the ID populated on the Account that is being updated. You could either create a new Account instance or strip out any other populated fields.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Yep, that did it! (Found the solution from the last comment of [this thread](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DZMhQAO) yesterday but did not have time to update my post.) After loading the test Accounts, I created new Account instances with the Ids (same as the loaded test Accounts) and RecordTypeIds populated, then performed the DML update on the new Account instances. Thanks so much for following up!

Comment: @DanielBallinger (I'm a little new to posting on Stack Exchange--aside from upvoting, is there some way to denote that your reply contains the solution?)

Comment: You can write your own answer, and accept it after two days (not sure if this is from when the post was created or the answer). If you want to allow other users (ie, @Daniel) to edit it, you can mark it as community wiki, but you won't get rep for the answer. I'd give it a few hours to see if @DanielBallinger wants to post an answer, and if not, create your own answer, with attribution to other users or posts which helped you. You can't mark a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment discussion, start from the suggested answer in [Importing RecordType as test data with Test.loadData()](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/65153/102).

This corresponds to **Loading the Account records from a csv with no RecordTypeIds, then later dynamically assigning RecordTypeIds through Apex.**

As you found, if you attempt to directly assign the RecordTypeIds on the records that come out of `Test.loadData()` you end up with the error:

> Cannot specify any additional fields when marrying or separating a Person-Account: []

This can be worked around by having *only* the `RecordTypeID` and the `ID` populated on the Account that is being updated.

E.g.

```
RecordType personAccountRecordType = [Select Id from RecordType where ...];

List<sObject> personAccountsLoaded = Test.loadData(Account.sObjectType, 
                                    'personAccountDataWithoutRecordTypeIds');
List<Account> personAccounts = new List<Account>();
for(sObject pa : personAccountsLoaded) {
    Account personAccount = new Account(Id = pa.Id);
    personAccount.RecordTypeId = personAccountRecordType.Id;
    personAccounts.add(personAccount);
}
update personAccounts;
```

Comment: I am unable to change the record type, because I get an error when loading the CSV data: `System.SObjectException: Business Account may not use Person Account field PersonHomePhone` - what should I do to get around this?